# An idempotent function $\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

I did an exam yesterday and this was one of the questions. I didn't have enough time to fully answer it so I wonder what the solution is:

> Let $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ be a continuous function with $f \circ f = f$. Show:
>
> 1. The image of $f$ is a closed interval (of course it may be unbounded).
> 2. If $f$ is differentiable then it is either the identity or a constant function.

I know if $f$ is differentiable, then by the chain rule:
$$f'(x) = (f \circ f)'(x) = f'(x)\cdot f'(f(x)). $$
That implies $f'(x) = 0$ or $f'(f(x)) = 1$ but it may be different depending on $x$.

Comment: If it is differentiable it must be continuous, in which case it could not take only two values, but the values in between too.

Comment: Does the original question specify a closed "interval" or a closed "set"? (Try $f(x)=\text{sgn} (x)$)

Comment: It specifies continuous. I forgot that...

Comment: Still,  take $f=x$ and statement 1 doesn't hold. It should be: the image of any closed interval is a closed interval

Comment: @GabrielR. The image of a function is the image of its domain which, in this case, is an interval.

Comment: My bad,  closed interval has a different meaning in French

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Answer to 1.

A continuous function is such that given any sequence $(x_n)$ such that $x_n\to x$, then  $f(x_n)\to f(x)$.

First, note that if $f$ takes two values $f(x_1), f(x_2)$, because of the [intermediate value theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_value_theorem), it must take all the values in between. This means that the image is an interval with possibly infinite endpoints.

To see why the interval is closed, suppose that $y$ is a limit point of the image, i.e. there exists a sequence of values $f(x_n)$ wich converges to $y$. The continuity of $f$ implies $f(f(x_n))\to f(y)$, so that $f(x_n)\to f(y)$ by idempotency. Since the limit is unique, this means that $f(y)=y$, so that $y$ is part of the image.

This proves that the image is a closed interval. I think the infinite endpoints must be allowed, take for instance $f$ to be the identity function: then the image is $\mathbb (- \infty,\infty)$.

### Answer to 2.

Your result says that at each point $x$, either $$f'(x) = 0 \text{ or } f'(f(x)) = 1. \label{a}\tag{1}$$
Evaluating this last statement at $y = f(x)$ and applying idempotency, we get that either $f'(y) = 0$ or $f'(y) = 1$ at each point $y$ in the image of $f$.

By part 1, we know that the image $I$ must be a closed interval.

If $I$ contains just one point, then $f$ is a constant. Otherwise, we know that $I$ is a proper interval, and $f | _I$ is either a constant or the identity in virtue of [Darboux's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux%27s_theorem_(analysis)) following [Emanuele Paolini's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/685845/123170) (since no other linear functions are idempotent).

We can readily rule out the case where $f|_I$ is a constant.
This would imply $f'(f(x)) = 0$ for all $x$ and so, by $\ref{a}$, $f'(x) = 0$ for all $x$ and $I$ reduces to a point.

If $f|_I$ is the identity, we will argue that $I = \mathbb R$.
Suppose the image of $f$ has an end on the right, $b$.
Then $b$ is the maximum value of $f$. Taking the limit from the left as $x \to b$ we find that $f(b) = b$, i.e. it takes its maximum value at $x=b$, which implies $f'(b) = 0$ [by the extremum value theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_theorem_(stationary_points)). However $f'(b) = 1$ taking the limit from the left, a contradiction. The argument is analogous for a lower bound $a$. Thus, $I=\mathbb R$ and $f$ is the identity.

Answer (score 5):

A differentiable function whose derivative is either 0 or 1 has constant derivative, in view of Darboux property: if the derivative has value 0 *and* 1 then it has also all the intermediate values.

Answer (score 1):

I now have the following for the case that $f$ is differentiable and surjective:

Take an $x \in \mathbb R$. It can be written as $f(y)$. Then either $f'(x)=0$ or $f'(f(x)) = f'(x) = 1$. Because of the Darboux property, only one of those can hold for all $x$ at once. $f'(x)=0$ is impossible because then $f$ would be constant and not surjective. So it must be $f'(x)=1$, i.e. $f(x)=x+c$. By idempotence $c=0$.